# Facebook FQL query friends of friends events doesn't work anymore?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

For some reason this following doesn't work anymore. The query just hangs and doesn't return anything. Ideas? Have they shutdown that particular query?

```
SELECT name, venue, location, start_time, eid FROM event 
WHERE eid IN (
       SELECT eid FROM event_member 
       WHERE (uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())  OR uid = me())
   )
AND start_time > now()
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook made some changes in the API and that may affect your request.

To check this, go to: Facebook > Apps > Your App > Settings > Advanced.
There is a "Migration" panel which those parameters:

**Events Timezone:**

> Enables real timezone support for events.  After this migration, event
>   times are returned as ISO-8601 formatted strings, even in FQL.

**October 2013 Breaking Changes:**

> The quarterly Platform changes that will be in effect on October 2,
>   2013.

You can check what [will be done](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) in the October breaking change, but your problem should be due to "Events timezone" because your are using datetimes for events in your FQL query. Try to disable the new API feature (check Disable and Save your settings).